# PHP cURL extension required

Tags: expresso

I am experiencing installtion error for ecommerce module with this below message.

Expresso Store requires the PHP cURL extension to be installed on your server.

Could you please anyone give me some input?

sus

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanatory to me.  You need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to install the cURL extension for PHP.

Comment: Thanks i have updated php ini file to activate that and now its working fine